# server freezing and cannot find reasons

Tags: centos, xeon, hanging

My server got random hanging, sometime 2 weeks sometime 2-3 days. I updated Kernel to from 3 to 4, the server is still freezing randomly. I did many test e.g. memtest86, CPU stress test. after the hanging I read dmesg and /var/log/message. and remote syslog. But I did not find any issues. this is my bootup log link http://pastebin.centos.org/137401/. Could you give some hints?

CentOS 7 with latest kernel
Supermicro Case with redundant power supplies
Supermicro X10DAX with latest BIOS version 
Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 128 GB
4 x 32 GB crucial DDR4 ECC RAM and insert to A1 B1 E1 and F1
Intel RAID-10 with four SATA 3 HDD

Comment: Is there anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: no there is no any error log